# Colored Cells and Cell Contents Aren't Aligned As Expected

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to color some cells in a table, with the cell contents being centered vertically as well as horizontally.  I can't seem to get the numbers - which seem to align with the header fine - to horizontally center inside the rectangles created by the cell colors.  The numbers don't seem to be quite vertically centered in the colored rectangles either.  I've reduced my complicated table to this MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
    \usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l C{0.1cm} C{0.1cm}}
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            header & \multicolumn{2}{l}{header} \\
            \midrule
            label & \cellcolor{green!40!black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{6}} & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{16}} \\
            label & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{7}} & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{18}} \\
            \bottomrule[1.25pt]
    \end{tabularx}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the relevant part of the table resulting from the MWE:

[image: MWEresult]

You can see the double digit numbers even get cut off.  Is anyone able to correct the alignment or are my expectations of `\LaTeX{}` too grand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your columns are too narrow (with your code you receive `Overfull \hbox` warnings); as soon as you increase the width, you get the desired result, Using `\extrarowheight` you can improved the vertical alignment:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
    \usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l C{0.3cm} C{0.5cm}} 
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            header & \multicolumn{2}{l}{header} \\
            \midrule
            label & \cellcolor{green!40!black}\textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{6}} & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{16}}  \\
            label & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{7}} & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{18}} \\
            \bottomrule[1.25pt]
    \end{tabular}    
}

{
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l C{0.3cm} C{0.5cm}} 
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            header & \multicolumn{2}{l}{header} \\
            \midrule
            label & \cellcolor{green!40!black}\textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{6}} & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{16}}  \\
            label & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{7}} & \cellcolor{black} \textcolor{lightgray!50!white}{\textbf{18}} \\
            \bottomrule[1.25pt]
    \end{tabularx}    
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why do you use `tabularx` environment without really using X columns?

Comment: OK. This one is yours :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina oh, for some reason i thought i needed tabularx to get my new column type to work.  i changed that, extrarowheight, got my complicated table to work with wider cells, and even adopted xcolor=table.  awesome.